# How to append data to a div based on the attribute?

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML as shown above

```
<div id="restmenu" class="restMenu">
   <ul>
      <section id="4" addlabel="Office" class="ulseWrap lielement">
         <div class="intit someclassss activeRest ">Office<span id="deleteOffice" class="inDelete"></span><span class="inEdit" title="Modify Address" name="Modify Address"></span></div>
      </section>
   </ul>
</div>
```

When clicked on lielement , i am getting response from the server and adding this particular lielemnt

Right now i am doing this way .

```
$("#restmenu").find('#'+locationname).append(ulhtml);
```

By default this is finding id .

Is it possible to find the `addlabel` attribute and add data to it ??

Means i need to find out the "Office" and add this data to it .

Comment: @PranavCBalan Its not a limitation with HTML5

Comment: $("#restmenu").find('#'+locationname).append(ulhtml); will be same as $('#'+locationname).append(ulhtml);

Comment: I have already answered @preethi jain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to append using attribute `addlabel`

```
$("#restmenu").find('section[addlabel="Office"]').append(ulhtml);
```

**NOTE** - Please make sure that `id`s must be unique through out the document

**EDIT** - As OP wants `addlabel` value dynamic, below is the code

Use some variable to store `addlabel` value and concatenate it in jQuery selector as shown below -

```
var locationName = "Office";// location name

$("#restmenu").find('section[addlabel="'+ locationName +'"]').append(ulhtml);
```

Comment: How to make this dynamic ??  Office is the location name .

Comment: @PreethiJain `$("#restmenu").find('section[addlabel="'+ locationname +'"]').append(ulhtml);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this for `dynamic` locationName :-

```
$("#restmenu").find('section[addlabel="'+locationName+'"]').append(ulhtml)
```